# Create a find method with PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

In the past I've worked with framework as `Slim` or `CodeIgniter`, both provide method such as `getWhere()`, this method return `true` or `false` if the array content passed to the `getWhere` was found on database table.
Actually I've created my own layer class that extends PDO functionality, my goal is create a method that take care to look for a specific database content based on the supplied parameters, currently I created this:

```
public function findRecordById($table, $where = null, $param = null)
{
    $results = $this->select("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE $where",$param);
    if(count($results) == 0)
    {
        return false; 
    }
    return true;
}
```

for search a content I simply do:

```
if(!$this->db->findRecordById("table_name", "code = :key AND param2 = :code",
            array("key" => $arr['key'], "code" => $arr['code']))){
  echo "content not found";
}
```

now all working pretty well but I think that the call on the condition is a bit 'too long and impractical, I would like to optimize everything maybe going all the content into an array or something, but until now I have a precise idea. Some help?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Uhm, I don't know what you don't understand but simply I want optimize my method `findRecordById`, now I have to pass the table name (where I need to find the record), the where clause and the parameters as array. I want optimize all and pass where and paremeters in one array or something like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't quite understand your question, but for the code provided I could tell that such a method should never belong to a DB wrapper, but to a CRUD class, which is a completely different story.

If you want to use such a method, it should be a method of a **Model** class, and used like this

```
$article = Article::find($id);
```

While for a database wrapper [**I would strongly suggest you to keep with raw SQL**](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/common_mistakes#select)

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE code = :key AND param2 = :code";
$data = $this->db->query($sql, $arr)->fetchAll();
```

is the clean, tidy, and readable code which anyone will be able to read and understand.

As a bonus, you will be able to order the query results using ODER BY operator.

Comment: Interesting article for the rest api, but I don't understand how you code example code could optimize my `find` method.

Comment: It explains that there should be no find method in the database wrapper at all

Comment: So you suggest to create an `exist` method for each model instead?

Comment: Not for each model but for the parent Model class only. From which all models will inherit it

Comment: The link I gave you is not on rest apis at all. In fact, it's exactly on the problems you have at the moment, due to wrong design of your wrapper. FetchColumn have to be applied to the statement, not the resulting array.